# How to write Many-to-Many Relation in Laravel 7.x for:

Tags: laravel

inn_categories:

```
          inn_cat_id (Primary Key)                        
          inn_cat_name
```

inn_posts :

```
          inn_post_id (Primary Key)
          inn_post_name
```

inn_posts_relation :

```
          inn_rel_id (Primary Key)
          inn_post_id  (Foreign Key)
          inn_cat_id  (Foreign Key)
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @venkateshEmala Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more context for your question so anyone can read your question and understand exactly what is it that you are asking for. Provide context for your sample codes so we know what do you mean by putting those codes in your question. Thank you for following the platform policy and rules. Your contribution will help everyone that has the same or similar questions,

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

On categories:

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Posts', 'inn_posts_relation', 'inn_cat_id', 'inn_post_id');
}
```

On posts:

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'inn_posts_relation', 'inn_post_id', 'inn_cat_id');
}
```

You doesn't need `inn_rel_id` in pivot table.

Modify pivot table and foreign keys name as needed.

You can find official documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Next time, make sure you share the code you have done so far.